# how to get a rain or Letters falling in Java

Tags: java, android, matrix

I found this code to get a Matrix effect (falling letters) in GitHub, but it doesn't work and I need your help to Tell me what's wrong, or give me suggestions; and thanks in advance.

when I try the app, I get a blank screen even I'm making the container linear Black, and the button doesn't appear.

**picture**

[image]

**the Code I'm using**

```
 MyMatrix mat = new MyMatrix(); 
            do {
                mat.compute();
                mat.print();
    try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {  }
            } while (true);
```

**the Class**

```
public class MyMatrix { 
    final int WIDTH=120,HEIGHT=10;
    char[][] buffer;
    int[] rank;
    
    public MyMatrix() {

        buffer = new char[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
        rank = new int[WIDTH];
                
        for(int i=0; i<HEIGHT; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<WIDTH; j++)
                buffer[i][j] = ' ';

        for(int j=0; j<WIDTH; j++)
            rank[j] = 0;

    }

    public void compute(){
        
        //move chars down line by line
        for(int i=HEIGHT-1; i>0; i--){
            for(int j=0; j<WIDTH; j++)
                buffer[i][j] = buffer[i-1][j];
        }
    
        //add new line
        for(int j=0; j<WIDTH; j++){
            buffer[0][j] = getChar(j);
            if(buffer[0][j]==' ')
                rank[j] = 0;
            else
                rank[j]++;
                
        }
        
    }

    public char getChar(int p){
    
        Random rand = new Random();
        
        //select a random integer
        // which points to a char between A-Z
        char n = (char)(rand.nextInt(25)+65);
        
        // randomly decide
        // whether to return the character or
        // or just return a blank space
        // so as to create character density effect
        return rank[p]>0?(rand.nextInt(100)<70? n:' '):(rand.nextInt(100)<1? n:' ');
    }
    
    public void print(){
            
        //print each row of buffer as a line
        for(int i=0; i<HEIGHT; i++)
            System.out.println(getLine(i));
        System.out.flush();
    }
    
    public String getLine(int row){
        
        String result="";
        
        for(int i=0; i<WIDTH; i++)
            result += buffer[row][i];
        
        return result;
    }
}
```

**source**

[link GitHub of the code](https://github.com/alpeshgit/MatrixWorld)

Comment: Where is the code you're using to display the matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you use does nothing to print to a UI screen in Android. It just prints stuff out to System.out the standard output (`System.out.println(getLine(i));`). So first run the code directly in your IDE and check you see the proper result on your program's output. Then you can take the matrix output and write text to your Android page.